# .each() not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm pulling information from XML and placing it into several div's that I'm building with the jquery each() and append() functions.

It works great in all browsers except for IE8. In IE8, the function does not seem to fire at all.

Does anyone know why this is?

```
var xml = '<questions><question1 text="When was the first solar photovoltaic cell    invented?"><choice>1940s</choice><choice answer="correct">1950s</choice><choice>1970s</choice><choice>1980s</choice><correct>Thats right</correct><wrong>It was in the 50s</wrong><correctanswer>The first modern solar cell was created by ATT Bell in 1954. One of the first uses for the technology was on early space satellites like the Vanguard 1.</correctanswer><wronganswer>The first modern solar cell was created by ATT Bell in 1954. One of the first uses for the technology was on early space satellites like the Vanguard 1.</wronganswer></question1></questions>';

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
currentQues = 1
curr = 'question' + currentQues;
$question = $xml.find(curr);

$question.find("choice").each(function(){
            x = $(this).attr("answer");
            ctext = $(this).text();
            $(".answers").append("<div class='ans'><input id='" + x + "' type='radio'><label>" + ctext + "</label></div>");
        });
```

Comment: With what jQuery version ?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the debugger?

Comment: And you know those variables are global right ?

Comment: What is that selector you are using in the find? Are you sure the find function is just not returning nothing? `console.log($question.find("choice").length == 0 ? "Nada" : "Yada");`

Comment: Version is v1.7.2 and like i said, it works in all browsers except for IE8

Comment: @user1836025 - can you provide a fiddle for us?

Comment: -just updated the code some to try to make it more clear

Comment: Seriously, what's `curr` ?

Comment: added curr too, sorry

Comment: Most likely IE sees the xml as invalid. place the xml string in an xml document and open it with IE to see why.

Comment: The XML parser in IE8 is crap, and you're probably not getting the elements, otherwise .each would work just fine in IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWfcZ/)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      var xml = '<questions><question1 text="When was the first solar photovoltaic cell    invented?"><choice>1940s</choice><choice answer="correct">1950s</choice><choice>1970s</choice><choice>1980s</choice><correct>Thats right</correct><wrong>It was in the 50s</wrong><correctanswer>The first modern solar cell was created by ATT Bell in 1954. One of the first uses for the technology was on early space satellites like the Vanguard 1.</correctanswer><wronganswer>The first modern solar cell was created by ATT Bell in 1954. One of the first uses for the technology was on early space satellites like the Vanguard 1.</wronganswer></question1></questions>';

      var appendtext = "";

      xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
      $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
      currentQues = 1
      curr = 'question' + currentQues;
      $question = $xml.find(curr);


    $question.find("choice").each(function(){
        x = $(this).attr("answer");

        if (typeof x !== 'undefined' && x !== false) {

                 ctext = $(this).text();
                 appendtext =  "<div class='ans'><input id='" + x + "' type='radio'><label>" + ctext + "</label></div>";

        }
    });
    $( ".answers" ).append(appendtext );
});
```

**Explanation:** You have to check if `x` is undefined. Meaning check for `<choice>` tags that has `answer` attr - otherwise don't add append text.

Also, I tested it on IE8 compatible version - works fine.